# Unsolved Problems in Elementary Game Theory With Real-World Applications

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I am looking for some unsolved problems in elementary game theory (no calculus, etc.) that have real-world applications and are not impractical to solve. It would be great if the games are not well-known.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordination games such as

9,9 0,7

7,0 8,8

are unsolvable in a sense (risk dominance vs payoff dominance). But in the real world, they might very well be part of a repeated game or be a widely played game, where that context strongly suggests a conventional coordination point. Real world examples are new electronic product standards, eg, USB standards.